# Calling Vue method from inside mounted function

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In my Vue mounted code, I am calling a function test via this.test(). This works fine as intended.

When however I am calling this.test() from the new ResizeObserver function, I am getting an error

> this.test is not a function

I understand that this is because the `this` there is now pointing to the resizeObserver. What I do not understand is what I should use there instead. Removing the this also gives an error.

I have the following Vue code

```
  mounted: function() {
    this.test();

    new ResizeObserver(function() {
        this.test();
      }).observe(this.g("tC"));
  },
  methods: {
    test: function() {}
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should either bind "this" to the function passed to ResizeObserver

```
  mounted: function() {
    this.test();
    new ResizeObserver(function() {
        this.test();
      }.bind(this)).observe(this.g("tC"));
  },
```

Or use an arrow function (if your environment supports ES6) since arrow functions use "this" value of the outer scope:

```
  mounted: function() {
    this.test();
    new ResizeObserver(() => {
        this.test();
      }).observe(this.g("tC"));
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

It works for me like this

```
  mounted: function() {
    $vm = this;

    new ResizeObserver(function() {
        $vm.test();
      }).observe(this.g("tC"));
  },
  methods: {
    test: function() {}
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Use Arrow functions to bind scope

```
 new ResizeObserver(()=> { //--> Arrow Function
        this.test();
      }).observe(this.g("tC"));
```