# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined [this.$inertia.get('/idea_details', {}); within Vue component's mounted()]

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-component, closures, inertiajs

I'm trying out inertiajs with laravel/vue, and trying to navigate to a new page/url with the following code:

```
this.$inertia.get('/idea_details', {});
```

It blows up with the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
```

Presumably this means it (the page?) has no idea what '$inertia' is -- or doesn't care, it does not exist.

I'm making this call within the 'Dashboard.vue' component/page, with almost full code below:

```
 41         </div>
 42     </breeze-authenticated-layout>
 43 </template>
 44 
 45 
 46 <script>
 47     import BreezeAuthenticatedLayout from '@/Layouts/Authenticated'
 48 
 49     export default {
 50         components: {
 51             BreezeAuthenticatedLayout,
 52         },
 53         mounted(){
 54             console.log('test from the Dashboard.vue component...');
 55             $(document).ready( function () {
 56                 var table = $('#myTable').DataTable();
 57 
 58                 $('#myTable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
 59                     var data = table.row( this ).data();
 60                     alert( 'You clicked on '+data[0]+'\'s row' );
 61 
 62                     // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
 63                     this.$inertia.get('/idea_details', {}); 
 64 
 65                 } );
 66             });
 67         }
 68     }
 69 
 70 </script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

I'm a relative newbie with this entire stack, including web components and npm and etc., so very possible I'm missing something very elemental.

This is Laravel 8 using one of their 'Starter Kits' -- Breeze and Intertiajs:

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/starter-kits#laravel-breeze-installation

Thanks!

...adding that, the Vue beta extension for Chrome seems to think it sees/knows about Inertia, as you can see in this screenshot:

[image]

...got part of this working. seems at least two parts i was missing or doing wrong:

1. import then declare the object I want access to (Inertia)
   lines 51 and 57 of code snippet below.
2. use only within the 'methods' declaration section of the 'export default' within the  tag -- as opposed to the 'mounted' section -- which I have no figured out yet.

```js
49 <script>
50     import BreezeAuthenticatedLayout from '@/Layouts/Authenticated'
51     import Inertia from '@inertiajs/inertia'
52 
53 
54     export default {
55         components: {
56             BreezeAuthenticatedLayout,
57             Inertia
58         },
59         methods: {
60             hi(){
61                 // corresponds to 'Route::get('/idea', ...' 
62                 //   in routes/web.php. ie don't use a '/' here
62                 this.$inertia.visit('idea',{});
```

...proposed solution would be something like this (I thought), but it's wrong, or at least not right:

```
 58                 $('#myTable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
 59                     var data = table.row( this ).data();
 60                     alert( 'You clicked on '+data[0]+'\'s row' );
 61 
 62                     // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
 63                     this.$inertia.get('/idea_details', {}); 
 64 
 65                 }.bind(this)); // create closure?
```

The 'table' here is a DataTables.net table. The 'data' is an array of the table's columns, in my case 3 of them: 'id', 'codename', 'tagline'. Now, no matter which row of the datatable you click on, you will always get the first/top row of the table.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was finding a way to get the proper scope, and it seems to be answered here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54072713/1965936

...ok, figured out that binding 'this' is possibly part of the answer, or at least hints at an answer, but not sure how to actually fix this yet.

...ok, this could potentially qualify as an actual answer:

```
187   $( "#myTable tbody" ).on( "click", "tr", {thisArg: this}, function(event) {
188       let data = myDataTable.row(this).data();
189       console.log(event.data.thisArg); // 'Proxy {route:...'
190       event.data.thisArg.modal_title=data.codename;
191       event.data.thisArg.modal_body=data.tagline;
192       event.data.thisArg.showModal=true;
193       event.data.thisArg.hello(); // call your 'hello()' method
194   });
```

The key here is that `this` on line 188 is not the same as `this` specified previously on line 187 (as an argument).

The hack/fix in this case was to use the third argument of the [jQuery '.on()' event handler function](https://api.jquery.com/on/) to pass in the original `this` (the component) as a variable -- specified here as 'thisArg'.

You also have to explicitly name the 'event' argument to the 'handler' function -- this is the official function signature at the link:

```
.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )
```

The `data` param is just an object with key/value pairs -- whatever you want it/them be.

Then to access that data, i specify the key within that `data` argument:

```
event.data.thisArg
```

`thisArg` is the component I want to manipulate, call methods on, etc.

When I run `console.log(thisArg)`, I see this:

```
Proxy {route: ƒ, confirm: ƒ, close: ƒ, cancel: ƒ, …}
```

This is presumably a Stringified version of my component, as `confirm`, `close`, and `cancel` are my first three listed `methods()` in the component.